Arm scatter file custom section
I want to add a custom section just after the RESET at a fixed address offset for the ARM toolchain.
But scatter file loading assigns the custom section (.app_version) to some random location.
file: linker.sct
LR_FLASH __FLASH_START __FLASH_SIZE
ER_FLASH __FLASH_START __FLASH_SIZE 
{
    *.o (RESET, +First)
    * (.app_version)  /* e.g. at offset 0xEC */
    *(InRoot$$Sections)
    .ANY (+RO)
    .ANY (+XO)
}

I have tried it using the attribute((at(0xEC)) in the source file, but that also did not work.
Also, try creating a new execution region with offset and moving the *(InRoot$$Sections) but that is not allowed by the compiler, giving an error message (eg._main.o, _scatter.o, etc) object should be in the root execution region.
I want the section .app_version should be placed at a fixed offset just after the RESET/Vector table.
Can anyone help with this?
